# How to cache document/page to Vercel Web Server at NuxtJs SSR app

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I've set up an SSR NuxtJS project using Vercel and I want to cache to Vercel Web Server the html page file for better performance and not just adding response headers for client/browser caching. So I want to cache (to be **x-vercel-cache: HIT** as [here](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/caching#x-vercel-cache) mentions) the GET request of each page with `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

[image]

Searching inside the [Vercel Config](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration) I couldn't find anything related ...
I tried to add a package ([nuxt-ssr-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-ssr-cache)) for ssr cache inside the Nuxt project, but it didn't work as expected.

Any idea how could I achieve that ?!?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the headers of the response so the CDN can understand you want to cache the response. With Node.js (vanilla):

```js
res.setHeader('Cache-control', 's-maxage=120, stale-while-revalidate);
```

With `vercel.json`:

```json
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/example/:path*",
      "headers" : [
        {
          "key" : "Cache-Control",
          "value" : "s-maxage=120, stale-while-revalidate"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about "vercel.json" in the [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/headers).